# Custom font delayed loading in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On page load in IE, the page is displayed for a fraction of second with no custom font, then it renders fine. But this behavior is not in Chrome. Any suggestion how to prevent it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use always google fonts for websites in this way.

**Add in Html**

```
<head>
<title>Website Name</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**Add in CSS**

```
body{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

font loading speed depend on the size of the font, your browser cache, and the bandwidth of your network.

that aside, why there is no problem in chrome? it might be because of the way the browser was designed. IE is old, and I bet that your chrome is brand new. so it might be that chrome has a better thread management than IE.

what to do to minimize the effect? you can try to reduce the size of your font. for example, if you use the font for icons, then you can remove the icons that you are not using.

another way is to use windows build in fonts for display in IE, that way, the browser does not need to download fonts. for example, you can use `century gothic`, `impact`, or `calibri`